# Template Error. Trying to migrate from webapp+python2.5 to webapp2+python2.7.4

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, django-templates

Hello I get the following error when trying to migrate from python2.5/webapp to python2.7.4/webapp2 in Google App Engine.

```
File "C:\main\main.py", in get
**compiled_template = template.Template(template_file.read())**

File "C:\Program Files     (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\_internal\django\template\__init__.py", line 156, in __init__
if settings.TEMPLATE_DEBUG and origin is None:

 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\_internal\django\conf\__init__.py", line 31, in __getattr__
assert self.holder, 'settings has not been configured in this thread'

AssertionError: settings has not been configured in this thread
```

Here is the complete code:

---

main.py file

---

```
import webapp2
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings' 
try:
    from google.appengine.dist import use_library
    use_library('django', '1.2')
except:
    pass
from django.conf import settings
_ = settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
          'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']
        }

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), './src/main.html'); 
        path = os.path.normpath(path);
        template_file = open(path) 
        compiled_template = template.Template(template_file.read()) #THIS GIVES THE ERROR
        template_file.close()  
        self.response.out.write(compiled_template.render(template.Context(template_values)))
        return

        app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
                             [
                              ('/', Main)
                             ],                                   
                             debug=True
                             )
```

---

app.yaml file

---

```
application: main
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

derived_file_type:
- python_precompiled

libraries:
- name: yaml
  version: "3.10"
- name: webob
  version: "1.1.1"
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: django
  version: "1.2"

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

Could you please help with this? Thank you!
(Note that the line giving error worked perfectly in webapp+python2.5. It is only after migrating to webapp2+python2.7.4 that I have started seeing this error.)

Comment: Take care. This from google.appengine.ext.webapp is depricated. Use full django or jinja2 if you only use templating. Webapp2 will help you, using jinja2: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/jinja2.html

Comment: Also, I don't think you have to declare webob in the libraries, as it is automatically pulled in by webapp2.

Comment: @voscausa Thanks. Have now moved to Jinja2. Porting from Django to Jinja2 was surprisingly pretty straightforward. Regarding Django error, GAE "migration" page doesn't list such issues. Although deprecated, it doesn't call-out that we will run into errors - which I think it should for everyone's benefit. Thanks again though.

Comment: @rGil Thanks! Removed from yaml file.

Comment: Yes, I moved to Jinja2 without any problems and with a lot of benefits.